# Creating a block using lists in Scala

Tags: scala

Given a 4 x 4 grid of type 
`List[List[Int]]`
, I need to create 4 blocks of (2 x 2) grids, I cant understand how to do this recursively.

For example, if I am given block 0, I need to show the values of row 0 and row 1 of column 0 and column 1. But how can I select the first 2 rows of the first 2 columns without printing the rest of the columns.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to be able to do this generically? Get 4 blocks of (n/2 x n/2) blocks? Or is it just the 4 x 4 to 4 (2 x 2) blocks?

Comment: 4 X4 to 4 (2x2) it has to be recursive.

Comment: It's really best not to do that recursively for a one off solution.

Comment: the excercise asks for it recursively.. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods such as `take`, `drop`, `grouped`, and `splitAt` to divide rows and columns in half.

It's then a matter of recursively doing this, dividing each grid into quarters at each step of the recursion, until you reach the smallest grid desired (presumably, 2x2).

Of course, if you only need to divide 4x4 into 2x2, there's no need to recurse at all.

Answer (score 0):

Following can take as a start,

```
scala> val m = (1 to 16).toList.grouped(4).toList
m: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4), List(5, 6, 7, 8), List(9, 10, 11, 12), List(13, 14, 15, 16))

scala> def takeQuod(r:Int, c:Int) = m.grouped(2).toList(r).map(_.grouped(2).toList(c))
takeQuod: (r: Int, c: Int)List[List[Int]]

scala> takeQuod(0,0)
res26: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(5, 6))
```